# Jquery keyup function is very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery keyup function is very slow. i am outputting the text on image. but the output is very slow.

Following is the html, JS, PHP code that i run. The code is running fine on my side but the problem is that it is very slow almost 5 to 10 seconds to write a letter. Is there any way to speed up the process. Kindly help.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 //PURE PATH TO IMAGE GENERATING PHP FILE
 var base = jQuery(".preview img").attr("src");
 
 //GATHER IMAGE FOR FIRST TIME
 jQuery(".preview img").attr("src",base+'?'+jQuery("#realtime-form").serialize());
  
 //KEYUP EVENT AND NEW IMAGE GATHER
 jQuery("#realtime-form input,textarea").stop().keyup(function(){
  jQuery(".preview img").attr("src",base+'?'+jQuery("#realtime-form").serialize()); 
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://nameonbirthdaycake.com/scripts/client-side.js"></script>

<div id="mainwrapper" class="preview">
<div id="box-1" class="box">
<img class="downloadable" src="http://nameonbirthdaycake.com/scripts/write.php?user_input=Enter+the+Name&postid=7">
</div>
<form id="realtime-form" action="" method="post"><strong>Enter the Name</strong>
<input id="realtime-form" maxlength="12" name="user_input" type="text" value="Enter the Name"/>
</form></div>
```

```html
<?php
header ('Content-type: image/png');
if(isset($_GET["postid"])){
 $post=(int)$_GET["postid"];
 
 if ($post==7){
  $userinput = $_GET["user_input"];
  $image=imagecreatefrompng(__DIR__ . "/images/bg.png"); 
  $font = __DIR__ . '/fonts/PR8Charade.ttf';
  $col1 = imagecolorallocate($image, 129, 125,11);
  $text_size1 = 36;
  $xposition1 = 245;
  $yposition1 = 380;
  $angeldirection1 = 50;
  imagettftext($image, $text_size1, $angeldirection1, $xposition1, $yposition1, $col1, $font, $userinput);
  imagepng($image);
  imagedestroy($image);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it actually related to your jQuery code?  What happens if you hit the URL that's being generated for the image source directly, does the PHP image generation execute quickly enough?  Does the file download to the browser in a reasonable amount of time etc?

Comment: You've redundant reference of Jquery. Remove one of the jquery reference.

Comment: Yest @JamesThorpe the image is generating fairly quickly. you can see it here: http://nameonbirthdaycake.com/cool-birthday-cake-with-name/

Comment: which reference is redundant @NileshThakkar

Comment: why you are using 2 jquery libraries ?

Comment: Jquery.min.js and jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: removing these libs don't have any effect @NileshThakkar